# Can kotlin coroutines be used like java Timer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm wondering if I can use kotlin coroutines as a Timer in order to remove the maximum Java references from my code. Basically I made a example where I use the class Timer to handle a chronometer display (milliseconds precision). Look (note to the java imports):

```
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.FlowLayout
import java.util.*
import java.util.Timer

class Screen : JFrame() {

  private var label = JLabel("--")
  private var timer: Timer? = null

  init {
    setSize(600, 200)
    defaultCloseOperation = 3
    layout = FlowLayout()
    val bt = JButton("toggle timer")
    bt.addActionListener {
      if (timer == null) {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        timer = Timer()
        timer!!.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
          override fun run() {
            label.text = "elapsed milliseconds: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}"
          }
        }, 0, 1)
      } else {
        timer!!.cancel()
        timer = null
      }
    }

    add(label)
    add(bt)
    setLocationRelativeTo(null)
    isVisible = true
  }
}

fun main() {
  Screen()
}
```

I also tried replace the classic Timer by some coroutines code and got this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Job
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.awt.FlowLayout
import javax.swing.JButton
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JLabel

fun create(someCallback: () -> Unit) = CoroutineScope(Job()).launch {
  while (true) {
    someCallback()
    delay(1L)
  }
}

class Screen : JFrame() {

  var label = JLabel("--")
  var localJob: Job? = null

  init {
    setSize(600, 200)
    layout = FlowLayout()
    val bt = JButton("toggle timer")
    bt.addActionListener {
      if (localJob == null) {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        localJob = create { label.text = "elapsed milliseconds: ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}" }
      } else {
        localJob!!.cancel()
        localJob = null
      }
    }

    add(label)
    add(bt)
    setLocationRelativeTo(null)
    isVisible = true
  }
}

fun main() {
  Screen()
}
```

I think the two codes shows basically the differences between the implementations. Anyway, my questions is if I can simply do this in terms of performance in comparison to Timer class. Also, if there's a better way to do this behavior instead of using coroutines feel frfee to suggest!

Answer (score 2):

use [flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html) , pay attention to the first launch block below

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

val clicks = MutableStateFlow(false)

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            clicks.withIndex().collectLatest { (idx, value) ->
                if (value) {
                    while (true) {
                        delay(1)
                        println("$idx label.text = ${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        launch {
            clicks.value = true
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = false
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = true
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = false
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = true
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = false
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = true
            delay(20)
            clicks.value = false
            delay(20)
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know much about swing, when button get click, toggle the value and set it to clicks, now some explanation

when event come in, `collectLatest` will **first cancel the last launched coroutine within collectLatest** and then launch a new one with current value, so every time you click, previous launched `while(true)` is cancelled，so you dont have to deal with the cancel event, i think this is the most neatly solution for your case

Answer (score 1):

With or without coroutines, you shouldn't use a timer that creates its own thread. Swing has [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html), so you'd use that. You can also launch a coroutine inside `Dispatchers.Swing` (from the [`kotlinx-coroutines-swing`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-swing/index.html) artifact) and use a loop like you have, but I'd prefer to use the native timer even if I was using coroutines because I'd trust its timing more.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Anyway, my first intention of using only-kotlin code is because I'm trying port some beckend code from JVM to Android (or even Javascript, in the future). Because this I thought using coroutines or flow (as @Minami suggested) should be worth it.